# Detect rotation on Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm searching for a way to detect the repaint of the WebView in Android to have the correct value of inner DOM element. I need this because I use an Javascript Interface to place a view over the webview.

View.onlayoutChange didn't do the job because it's sending before html element are repositionned (for responsiveness eg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

The only whay I've found is to store a `protected int mOrientation;`

on the onLayoutChange I check if the orientation has changed, return if not or save the current orientation `mOrientation =  getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;`

Moreover, the size of WebView inner DOM element has some delay ro be changed on rotation so I have delayed my code of 200ms so the DOM element are dimensionate correctly

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code
        }
    }, 200);
```